# Understanding Generic method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I moved from Java to C# and I am automating webservices in C#. There is a piece of code which is calling below method for converting the XML document to String

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(filePath + fileName);            
var xml = document.ToXml();

public static string ToXml<T>(this T toSerialize) where T : class
```

Can someone explain me what exactly the above method is doing, i understand the return type is String but what is this piece of code meant `ToXml<T>(this T toSerialize) where T : class`

Can someone also explain me what is meant by "generic"?

Comment: that's called extension method

Comment: This is an Extension method. Read about Extensions first, then head over to Generics

Answer (score 3):

It's an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

`public static string ToXml<T>(`**`this`**`T toSerialize) where T : class`

And a [generic one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857180/what-does-t-denote-in-c-sharp) at that, [constrained to reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786774/in-c-sharp-what-does-where-t-class-mean):

`public static string ToXml`**`<T>`**`(this`**`T`**`toSerialize)`**`where T : class`**

This means that you can call the method on any reference type:

```
var foo = new YourClass
{
    Bar = "Baz"
};
string xml = foo.ToXml<YourClass>();
```

And because the generic parameter type is used as a reference type, you can let it be [inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099812/what-are-implied-generic-type-parameters), omitting the generic argument:

```
string xml = foo.ToXml();
```

You could also just use `File.ReadAllText()` to load a text file into a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string ToXml<T>(this T toSerialize) where T : class
```

Let me break it down for you

```
<T>                  // This is the templated or generic type name.
where T : class      // This syntax restricts the generic type to be a class (as opposed to a struct)
this T toSerialize)  // The "this" keyword here can be ignored as it has nothing to do with the generics. It just tells that the caller can call this method like toSerialize.ToXml() instead of ContainingClass.ToXml(toSerialize)
```

In C#, you may or may not have to explicitly provide the generic type information at the call site, depending on the situation. In your case, it will be resolved without need for explicit specification

An explicitly specified call would like like

```
var xml = document.ToXml<XmlDocument>();
```

As you already have realized the `var` keyword is used instead of explicitly specifying `string`, since the compiler can infer the type very easily from the context.

You can read up on [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and the [contraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). Also, you can read up on [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). This should get you a solid understanding of the syntactical elements involved